# Enforcing a Unique List of Values with Lombok or Mongo annotations on Data Model

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, lombok

Is there a clean way to enforce that all values in the list response are unique using annotations. Ideally, I wouldn't want to write out separate code just to enforce a unique list of addresses.

In the below code I want my HashSet of addresses (       HashSet addresses) to only have unique values

```
import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * User Address data class reflects the list of addresses each customer will send us
 *
 * {
 *   "accountId": "234234234",
 *   "addresses": [
 *     "234234242423423423423",
 *     "909897897981231231233",
 *   ]
 * }
 */
@Document(value="dbname")
@Data
public class UserAddresses {

    @Id
    private String accountId;

    private HashSet<String> addresses;

}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question: a `Set` will never contain duplicates (according to `equals/hashCode`).

Comment: For some reason, a HashSet was allowing duplicates, but after changing the line to a Set it worked.     private HashSet<String> addresses;

Comment: Nope, no implementation of `Set` will ever allow duplicates. It is _the core definition_ of a set to not allow duplicates. There must be something else wrong with your code, e.g. a faulty or missing `equals` or `hashCode` implementation on the keys.

Answer (score -1):

Simply changing my data structure from a HashSet to a Set fixed my issue:

```
import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * User Address data class reflects the list of addresses each customer will send us
 *
 * {
 *   "accountId": "234234234",
 *   "addresses": [
 *     "234234242423423423423",
 *     "909897897981231231233",
 *   ]
 * }
 */
@Document(value="dbname")
@Data
public class UserAddresses {

    @Id
    private String accountId;

    private Set<String> addresses;

}
```